# Display problem raspberry pi 4 b

Tags: hdmi, display

i have a problem when i change the resolution i don't get the picture.

At a resolution of 2560×1440 everything works

but when I set it to 1920x1080 I don't get a picture.

Comment: wouldn't that be an issue with the display device? what resolutions does it support?

Comment: also, how are you setting the resolution to 1920x1080?